# Error al escribir from ... import library

Tags: python, importación, packages

Estoy intentando importar unos módulos en python pero no lo consigo, busque ayuda en internet pero no hay nada. El error que provoca es el siguiente; **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.**

En exercise.py estoy tratando de importar un modulo que se encuentra en la carpeta choose_operating_system, especificamente clean_console.py, pero al momento de escribir **from ...choose_operating_system.clean_console import Clean,** me da el error.

Este es el árbol de directorio que trabajo.

[image: Directory Tree]

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner `choose_operating_system/clean_console` para identificar el directorio?

Comment: Esto es un paquete que has creado e instalado, o solo una distribución de carpetas?

Comment: @RubialesAlberto yo lo he creado.